# Getting Jakarta Feedparser up in a remote Maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons, sonatype

I short I want to get the [Jakarta Feedparser](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/feedparser/) project up in a remote Maven repository (the project is currently dormant).

The source is over here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/dormant/feedparser/trunk/ (it's a Maven project)

I have been looking at [Sonatype](http://www.sonatype.org/) and I'm might be missing something here, but is it as simple as logging a support ticket and pointing them to the SVN source repository (https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide)?

If so I'm not 100% sure what the groupId should be, as the pom.xml gives the generic "org.apache.commons" as its groupId?

P.S. I did try and contact the project owner but with little success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources seem to be left in a migration state. There is a pom.xml but there is no src/main/java folder. There is also a build.xml which indicates its more of an ant build. the parent contains no modules so it looks unfinished.

Did you check out the sources and try to build it? If it does not compile it cant be added to a repository.

If it can be fixed you may add it to github creating a repository: http://blog.rueedlinger.ch/2012/09/use-github-as-maven-remote-repository/

the groupid would be org.apache.commons, the artifactId commons-feedparser. Most other libs from commons follow this convention.

Comment: Ja it built fine. 'mvn package' did the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the Github direction. Sounds like a pretty good idea, but just to be clear, is Sonatype not an option, or do you simply prefer going the Github route?

Comment: I would not upload it to sonatype since the project is dormant and not actively maintained and only used by you (?). If you distribute a product and others require the jar as well then sonatype may be an option. So either revive it or don't put it into a common repository unless it is used by a larger set of people. It is also possible to get it into central: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html
But since it is not an official apache project using their groupId might not be in their sense.